# Is there a way to determine what object is using an Email Template?

Tags: soql, email, email-template, case

I want to know if there is a way you can maybe query the database to determine what object might be using an Email Template? Kind of like when you click Field Update object and you can see what rules are using it?

The reason I ask is I have this email template that is getting sent out, but I can't find out what actually is sending it out. I've checked all the Email Alerts, all the Workflow Rules, and all the Flows and all the processes in the Process Builder, as well as the email settings in the Case Assignment rules, but nothing. So now I'm at a loss to see what is actually sending out this email.

Comment: Could be Apex.... Use the dev console. Go to Edit -> Search in Files (CTRL+SHIFT+H) and see if `setTemplateId` gets any hits.

Comment: Good suggestion, but no hits.